# Product of practical number times one of its divisor, is a practical number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

A practical number $n$ is a natural nonzero number such that all positive numbers less than $n$ can be written as a sum of distinct divisors of $n$.

In [this link](https://pls.scienze.unipd.it/matematica/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2018/07/2018.-MJ-Casagrande.-Articolo-Egypt.pdf), we have:

Theorem 3.2.2: The product of a practical number by one of its divisor, is a practical number.

Proof: Take $p$ practical and $d$ a divisor of $p$. Let us prove that $p\cdot d$ is also practical. For this, take $n<p\dot d$.

**If** $n<p$, since $p$ is practical then $n$ is a sum of distinct divisors of $p$, which are divisors of $p\cdot d$.

**Else** suppose that $k_1\cdot p \leq n < k_2\cdot p$ with $k_1$ and $k_2$ consecutive and $k_1<k_2\leq d$. In this case, we write $n=k_1\cdot p + r$ where $r<p$.
Then, $r$ is a sum of divisors of $p$ (which are divisors of $p\dot d$). Now, for $k_1\cdot p$, since $d$ divides $p$, we have $p=\lambda\cdot d$ and $k_1\cdot p=k_1\cdot \lambda\cdot d$. Since $k_1<d$, it holds that $k_1\cdot \lambda<p$. Therefore, $k_1\cdot \lambda$ is a sum of divisors of $p$ and $k_1\cdot p=k_1\cdot \lambda\cdot d$ is a sum of that divisors multiplied by $d$.

My question is: how can we conclude that the divisors of $r$ and the divisors of $k_1p$ are distinct?

(Edited).

Remark: I know that one can use [Stewart - Sierpinski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Practical_number) to prove this result, but I would like to do it following the lines in [the provided link](https://pls.scienze.unipd.it/matematica/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2018/07/2018.-MJ-Casagrande.-Articolo-Egypt.pdf).

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: "this fact". What fact? The subject line is like an envelope for a letter: the letter doesn't start on the envelope. Make the body of the post contain all the relevant information.

Comment: All right mates, I will update the question - thank you for your feedback!

Comment: It looks like the concern you raise is real. For example, $18$ is a practical number. Let's say we wanted to show that $18\cdot 3$ is a practical number. Then this proof claims we can write $45=2\cdot 18+9$. We can write $9=9$ as a sum of divisors of $18$, which are in turn divisors of $18\cdot 3$. We have that $2\cdot 18=2\cdot 6\cdot 3$. $12=3+9$, so $2\cdot 18=9+27$. But now we are using $9$ twice. So I think you are right that this proof needs a bit more support.

Comment: @AlanAbraham that is true. But note that we can write the "first" $9$ as $3+6$, which are also divisors of $18$. So the question would be "how to guarantee that it is always possible".

Comment: Hint : Write the desired number as $k\cdot p+q$ with $q<p$ and use that $p$ is practical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proof is indeed incorrect.

Consider $p = 6$, $d = 3$, and $n = 17 < pd$. (It is easy to verify that $p = 6$ is indeed a practical number.) Then, since $17 = 2p + 5 = 12 + 5$, the proof is claiming that there exists two sets of natural numbers $S_{12}$ and $S_5$ such that the following are true:

- All elements in $S_{12}$ and $S_5$ are divisors of $pd = 18$, i.e., both sets must be subsets of $\{1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 18\}$.
- Sum of all numbers in $S_{12}$ is $12$.
- Sum of all numbers in $S_5$ is $5$.
- The two sets are independent, i.e., $S_{12} \cap S_5 = \emptyset$.

Based on only the first three conditions, we find that $S_5$ must be $\{2, 3\}$, while $S_{12}$ has three possible values: $\{1, 2, 3, 6\}$, $\{1, 2, 9\}$, and $\{3, 9\}$. However, in all cases, the last condition will be violated.

Comment: thank you for your great answer, you are completely right. A natural question now would be: Does anyone see a way of correcting the proof (but following a similar path) ?